# Converting XML in a SQL Server column to text

Tags: sql-server, xml, type-conversion

I need to convert a XML column to text when selecting it. The idea is that I want to retrieve the plain XML.

I have tried both `cast` and `convert` to `(n)varchar(max)`, however these seem to cut off my string after about 64kb (65591 chars) when retrieving it via ODBC.

Is there a way to convert the XML column to text? I imagine text will hold larger values.

I have tried the `cast()` approach in the `SELECT` statement and as a persisted computed column - no luck.

I have used Google and Stackoverflow for the past two hours without finding any solutions. Besides the fact that most of my Google queries return "FOR XML" usages (which is pretty much the opposite of what I need), the few hits that match what I am looking for suggest casting/converting to `varchar(max)`. This does not work for me. Maybe retrieving the data via ODBC is the issue.

Best regards!

Comment: Can you include the query you're running? Are you seeing the string truncated in SSMS? Or in an application? Casting to (n)varchar(max) should be the right approach. However SSMS has some funky rules around how it displays long strings. If it's happening somewhere else, I would venture a guess that some processor along the way is imposing the max length.

Comment: Why are you using ODBC? Seems overly legacy and troublesome..... can't you use a more suitable approach to get the data? (like the `System.Data.SqlClient` if you're using .NET)

Comment: @Xedni: It is truncated in the application and in SSMS. SSMS truncates it after approximately 8000 chars which is - as I have read - a known issue. However my application truncates it after said 64kb.

Comment: @marc_s: Unfortunately I have to use ODBC as the application requires this.

Comment: Can you include the .Net code responsible for pulling the XML in?

Comment: I am not running it in .Net. It is a query executed in a proprietary programming language via ODBC. The queries I have tried are as follows: `SELECT AnswerXML FROM Northwind;` `SELECT CAST(AnswerXML as nvarchar(max)) as AnswerXML2 FROM Northwind;` `SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(max), AnswerXML) FROM Northwind;`

Comment: I found a workaround: I can do an UPDATE where I write the CONVERT(nvarchar(max)) part into a TEXT column. That way the ODBC connection can read it as it does not cut off text columns after 64kb. Feel free to post an answer if you have a real solution to my problem as mine is merely a sloppy workaround (which also blows up the table's size unneccessarily and assumes that one has the right to create new columns.

Comment: Unfortunately my workaround also gets cut off after 64kb. Does anyone know any other solutions? I read about an idea of exporting the colum data via bcp, but my user lacks the EXECUTE permission required to do this.